# Handle status 429 in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I did a Twitter clone using rails api + react, just for study purposes.

I have quite simple logic of requests: click in a user, load its informations and tweets, requesting for the api. However, If I do this fast like 3 times, I receive the status 429 (too many requests) with the header `Retry-After: 5`.

There is a way to increase the number of requests in a given time? How would be the correct approach to handle with this in such common situation?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the error information you have shown is correct, It means **request** cannot be served due to the application's rate limit having been peaked for the resource.

> Rate limits are divided into 15 minute intervals. All endpoints
>   require authentication, so there is no concept of unauthenticated
>   calls and rate limits.

To overcome this situation, [here](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/RateLimiting.md) is an example from the documentation itself.

Comment: Yes. However, I'm not using the Twitter api itself, I did a "twitter" clone just for study, it's my application. It's a bit weir receive this error code in so little time (3 requests in sequence).

Comment: What do you mean a twitter _clone_ ? Where are you getting the **tweets** from ? Do you have them on your database ? Can you update your question with your code, would help in understanding it better.

Comment: Think in basic actions of Twitter: timeline, post tweets, trending topics, etc. I made my own simplified version of this application. It's my code, I run in my local machine, so it's my own API, that I'm consuming in my front-end. Because of this I was asking if, once I have total control of the application code (because I implemented it), there is a way to increase the number of requests allowed before error 429 (or which is the proper way to handle this).

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://sdqali.in/blog/2013/10/12/implementing-rate-limiting-in-rails---part-1/) on how to handle rate limit